# How to make global keychain in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, keychain

I need to create a keychain that can be used by any user.

When I check a keychain as shared in Keychain Acess->Edit->Keychain List, it just disappears and I can't see this keychain in the list anymore.

What's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: how did you create this keychain? if you did it in code, can you modify your question to show your code?

Answer (score 1):

Create the new keychain in

**/Library/Keychains/**

like the System.keychain, this way any user can access the keychain.